# Facebook shares for Facebook pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

A client of mine has setup a Facebook page i.e. `www.facebook.com/businessname`. They want to know the number of people that have 'shared' this page. Is this possible with the Graph API?

I've been looking through the documentation and googling. I've come up with plenty of examples about getting the number likes/shares for a domain outside of Facebook.

See the following example: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.appshack.tv

This returns the number of shares for this website.

But haven't found anything specific to a Facebook page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to screw up their nomenclature which is confusing.

The "number of shares" returned by your link is the number of times people have clicked the "like" button on the website.

In the Graph API you can get the "likes" counter for a facebook page which is the same thing.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Share button number is total engagement number not share number (share count)

You can [read here more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354421/facebook-share-button-number-is-total-engagement-number-not-share-number-share)